# Increase screen idle dim timeout

Tags: 11.10, screen, battery, backlight

On Ubuntu 11.10, when on battery, the screen dims after 10 seconds of inactivity. This is annoying because it is too short. Is there anyway to increase this timeout?

I know I can disable it, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This command should set the time to 60 seconds:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time 60
```

In earlier Ubuntu versions, this setting can be found with the `gconf-editor` under `gnome-power-manager`. See also [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1024735&page=2).

Comment: I'm absolutely comfortable using the terminal (and this worked great for me by the way), but I sure do wish Ubuntu 11.10 let me change these kind of things through the "System Settings" GUI...

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't be configurable through the GUI settings.

Comment: `gconf-editor` does not exist in newer Ubuntus any more. Use `dconf-editor` instead.

Comment: This answer no longer works as of Ubuntu 14.04. It reports "No such key 'idle-dim-time'". Some of us would like to be able to do this from a script (e.g. as a wrapper for something that's going to play video to the screen), so the GUI is not usable. See my answer below.

Comment: This is no longer actual, newest ubuntu doesn't have this key. See BobDoolittle's answer

Answer (score 13):

The answer marked above from 'lumbric' no longer works for Ubuntu 14.04.

If you need to do this from a command (e.g. for a script wrapping something that plays video), you now need to run:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay <seconds>`

also useful in such a case might be disabling the screen lock:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`

Comment: Thanks, also `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay <seconds>"

Comment: @Bohr: useful. But if I were writing a wrapper around something that played video, I might not know how long it is. So I'd probably disable it first, and declare a "trap 0" function that re-enabled it on exit, using 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true'. That way it would disable the screen lock exactly as long as I need it to be. Of course that's vulnerable to signals that can't be handled, like SIGKILL but that's unlikely in practice.

Comment: Works like a charm in 22.04! This should be accepted anwesr nowadays

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `idle-delay` is currently set to 300 seconds, while the screen dims after 30 already. I'm guessing `idle-delay` is the time before the screensaver is activated? Not the time until screen brightness is reduced?

Comment: agreed it's the current (2023) right answer for 22.04 (and probably most of recent versions)

Answer (score 1):

In 12.04, the setting using GUI now exists via **System Settings** → **Brightness and Lock**.

Comment: I'm using 12.04, all updates installed, and there's no setting to set the screen dim timeout in "Brightness and lock". The only "timeout" option on the "Brightness and lock" settings menu is to turn the screen off, which is not the same thing as dimming its brightness.