# Time to dim the screen in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: screen, 14.04, backlight, idle

Ok so it seems that the key in org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time is gone in the new Ubuntu version. Since the old method [Increase screen idle dim timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98184/increase-screen-idle-dim-timeout) doesn't work anymore are there any other ways to change this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the setting for idle dim time has changed schemas. Use org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay <value>
```

For the future, a great way to find a setting is to pipe list-schemas or list-recursively to grep. That's how I figured this one out:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep idle
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: BTW, this is equivalent to the "Turn screen off when inactive for # minutes" in **Brightness & Lock**, not exactly the time for "Dim screen to save power", it took about 60 second to dim the screen (brightness turned down to around 30%) when running on battery with 14.04, and I didn't see any schema that is related to this dim time stuff.

Answer (score 0):

this command helped in my case:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 180
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Gnome developers decided that user does not need any way to customize idle dim time and removed this option in [this commit](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-January/msg05001.html). After this patch, `dim-idle-time` was computed based on `idle-delay` (see @ruby answer) by dividing it by three. Few days later they decided that dividing by 3 is not good and changed this factor to 4/5 in [this commit](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-January/msg06329.html). Even though those arbitrary divider proved to be, well, arbitrary, they didn't restore any possibility to change this by user.

Note that Ubuntu is now using [unity-settings-daemon](https://code.launchpad.net/~unity-settings-daemon-team/unity-settings-daemon/trunk) which is a fork of `gnome-settings-daemon` with exactly the same code regarding screen dimming.